# Could not find generator 'rspec:install'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing

I am not able to run the command `rails generate rspec:install` in my terminal. it give me the following error:

```
Could not find generator 'rspec:install'. Maybe you meant 'jquery:install' or 'devise:install' or 'responders:install'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

Here is the gem in my Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-remote'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  # allow CORS for fonts, etc. for local dev
  gem 'rack-cors'

  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.1'
end
```

I have seen people suggest to put the following line of code in application.rb but I have tried this and it doesn't work:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework  :rspec
end
```

I have done `gem install rspec-rails` and `bundle install` but I still cannot run `rails generate rspec:install`

Any more suggestions?

Comment: Try to execute `bundle exec rails generate rspec:install`

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work :/

Comment: what rails version are you using?

Comment: im using Rails 4.2.0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with rails 6.0.3 and ruby 2.7.1.

I tried adding `rspec-rails` gem in the `:development, :test` group and out of the group.
I tried `spring stop` and `bundle exec generate rspec:install`, neither worked.

And I confirm that adding `rspec` gem to Gemfile (in my case in `:development, :test` group) solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your gem file add

```
gem 'rspec'
```

it cleared my problem,.. hope it will help u too..